# PropTypes validation fails in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component below which has `props` coming from parent component and I added propTypes for the whole `props` object. However, the lint fails with the below error message.

```
9:16  error  'data' is missing in props validation                                   react/prop-types
9:22  error  'data.text' is missing in props validation
```

**Excerpt from code**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Child = (props) => <div>{props.data.text}</div>

Child.propTypes = {
 props: PropTypes.object
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Because you don't have `data` or `data.text` in your `props`-- defining your proptypes as a single empty object is about as useful as not defining them at all.  Furthermore,  the way you have this defined you are defining `props.props` as an object...

Comment: add `PropTypes.object.isRequired`, you will get error in this declaration. `Proptypes` validates the properties passed inside the `props` object, not the object as a whole. `Typecheck` each property individually.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you have a few issues:

1. `PropTypes.object` is a very vague type declaration, and most linters will ding you for that
2. You are referencing properties of that object inside of your functional component that are not declared in your proptypes
3. You are using your prop declaration to attempt to refer to the props argument as a whole, rather than the properties within.

A more correct way to write all of this would be like so:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/* Note we destructure `data` directly from props in the args */
const Child = ({ data }) => (<div>{data.text}</div>);

Child.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({ // use `shape` to allow us to declare types of properties within
    text: PropTypes.string, // define the text property's type
  }), 
}
```

Additionally, you may want to define some of these items as required, or provide default entries.

Answer (score 1):

From Alexander Nied solution, I made it work writing the below way without using `shape`, I think it is more generic.

```
const Child = ({ data }) => (<div>{data.text}</div>);

Child.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that this helped you move forward and you found a solution that works for you :) One word of consideration-- while the generic solution may be appealing, I'd argue that type checking is actually _intended_ to be specific, and that you _want_ to capture all the possible options and define their types for completeness' sake. That's why many default React linting configurations will include  [eslint-plugin-react's "react/forbid-prop-types" with `object`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) by default. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this explains why I shouldn't use generic type such as object for props. I have type-checked every prop in components using `shape`. @AlexanderNied